# What if cache data in varnish cache is changed?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

What if some data that is saved in varnish cache is changed after sometime on backend server. Then when a request comes, then varnish return old data or updated data?

Answer (score 3):

The old data, or to be clear: it returns the data as it was at the time when it was cached if the expiry time of the cached object has not yet been reached. If you want it to update before that time you need to purge or ban the item in the cache. See the chapter on `Purging and banning` in the varnish documentation for details on implementation.